# How do I copy only the Objects from Array to another Array using .splice() method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, array-splice

I have an array like below and sorting it using `.localeCompare` method.
Once the sorting is done, I want to hoist those items within the Array which are having `children` item true.

Can refer this jsfiddle for the code:  https://jsfiddle.net/sarav4gs/npd2mchs/78/

```
var data = [
    {
        "item": "aaabb110",
        "recID": 15
      },
      {
        "item": "aaabbbccc1",
        "recID": 16
      },
      {
        "item": "ZTemplate 1",
        "recID": null,
        "children": [
            {
            "item": "zaa",
            "recID": 70
           },
          {
            "item": "Qualification 1",
            "recID": 73
          }]
      },
      {
        "item": "bbaacc1",
        "recID": 17
      },
      {
        "item": "bbaa005",
        "recID": 18
      },
      {
        "item": "ATemplate 2",
        "recID": null,
        "children": [{
            "item": "Qualification 1",
            "recID": 83
          },
          {
            "item": "Qualification 2",
            "recID": 84
          },
          {
            "item": "Custom",
            "recID": 86
          },
          {
            "item": "custom code",
            "recID": 87
          },
          {
            "item": "aaa",
            "recID": 89
          }
        ]
      }
    ];
```

to achieve that I am trying to slice the items which has children and copying it in a new array later push it in a same array at the top. (I tried with .splice, .unshift), but in the output it copies complete array in the first argument instead just as objects.

```
var CQTemplates = [];
var newData = data.filter(function(item,i){

    if(item.children){
    var removeAt = data.indexOf(item);
     var CQTemplateCodeItem = data.slice(removeAt, removeAt+1);
     pushAt = CQTemplates.length;
     CQTemplates[pushAt] = CQTemplateCodeItem[0];

  } 
   return item.children == undefined;  
})
```

Expected Output is something like this

```
Array [
  "itemsWithChildifAny? - sorted",  
  "itemsWithChildifAny? - sorted",
  "Item - sorted",
  "Item - sorted",
  "Item - sorted"
]
```

Comment: "*Once the sorting is done, I want to hoist those items within the Array which are having children item true*" - don't. Just sort them into the right place straight away!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to separate the objects with children and without children. You can try this,

### Using ForEach

```
var CQTemplates = [];
let withChildren = [];
let withoutChildren = [];
data.forEach(function(item){
  if(item.children){
    withChildren.push(item);
  }  else {
    withoutChildren.push(item);
  }  
})
```

### Using Filter

```
var withoutChildren = [];
var withChildren = data.filter(function(item,i){
    if(!item.children){
    withoutChildren.push(item);
    return false;
  }
  return true;
})

console.log('Combined array', [...withChildren, ...withoutChildren]);
```

Output will be like

[image: output]

Happy coding!!

Comment: where is the splice() method my friend

Comment: You can achieve it without splice() method itself, I can also do that with splice(). But question is do we need that neccessarily?

Comment: since the QA said he needs a splice(), try to answer him with what he needs, we know in programming, we can achieve the same thing using million of directions

Comment: @user123456 Thanks for your answer. This actually serves the purpose.

Comment: as @sivaragala mentioned, If I were to solve by .splice(), what am I missing or doing wrong in my code to achieve that?